# Is there a tool that will find html tags with class attributes that don't have a corresponding class in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have found http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/ which does about the opposite of what I want, identifying selectors in CSS that aren't used in HTML.

I want a tool that will find elements that have a class attribute but the class isn't defined in any CSS being loaded by the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the CSS file is correctly linked within your page and a part your project, then in VS.NET 2008 it'll give you a the standard little squiggle warning.

Comment: the problem is that many of the CSS files are dynamically added and I'd like to find the issues in the final page.

Answer (score 0):

No tools that I know of.

Seems like a good candidate for a short program, since you probably don't need to do this terribly often.

I'd regex out the `class="someclass"` from my source html, use the Web Developer's Toolbar in Firefox to get a concatenation of all my CSS, and regex out `.someclass', and then compare the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a find using a text editor in your css file for classes you find in your HTML.